# Add check constraint to column to only allow alphabetical values to entered into the row

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

I am creating a table and want to add a check constraint to two of the columns so that only alphabetical values can be inserted into the columns. Here is the table being created:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
    (
    Forename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    );
```

The forename and surname columns should only allow alphabetical values to be inserted. I have tried these two different check constraints however they did not work as I could still insert number values into the forename column:

```
CONSTRAINT FN_LETTERS_ONLY_CK CHECK(FORENAME NOT LIKE ‘%’ +’[^A-Z]’+’%’),
CONSTRAINT FN_LETTERS_ONLY CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(FORENAME, ‘^[[:ALPHA:]]+$’))
```

Comment: "Did not work" isn't terribly helpful. Did you really use curly quotes for those strings; and uppercase `ALPHA` instead of `alpha` in the second one? Either would cause an error, rather than allowing numbers to be inserted. But that second one should work otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant by did not work was that the constraint would not be applied and numbers would still be inserted into those columns without throwing an error. And about the uppercase ALPHA, I am new to SQL and did not think case mattered so thanks for telling me about case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression attempt looks almost right, except you have uppercase `ALPHA` which would cause an error on insert (ORA-12729: invalid character class in regular expression), and you've shown it with curly quotes which prevent it being created at all.

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
    (
    Forename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FN_LETTERS_ONLY CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(FORENAME, '^[[:alpha:]]+$')),
    CONSTRAINT SN_LETTERS_ONLY CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(SURNAME, '^[[:alpha:]]+$'))
);
```

Then testing that:

```
SQL> insert into person values ('abc','xyz');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into person values ('ab1c','xyz');
insert into person values ('ab1c','xyz')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (MY_SCHEMA.FN_LETTERS_ONLY) violated


SQL> insert into person values ('abc','xy2z');
insert into person values ('abc','xy2z')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (MY_SCHEMA.SN_LETTERS_ONLY) violated
```